# Facebook C# Sdk, Framework 3.5 and Microsoft.Contracts

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've downloaded the Facebook C# SDK. I'm at the point where I have a facebook token and am calling the method:

```
  var fb = new FacebookClient(token);
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
    Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0,  
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=736440c9b414ea16' or one of its dependencies
```

Any suggestions? I am using the .Net Framework 3.5.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The download link is on the right side of the page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992

Comment: Does this mean all my users have to install this?